# /var/named/chroot/var/named: device is busy

Tags: fedora, dns, bind

When I restart the named service, it gives me this error:

```
./etc/init.d/named restart

Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting named: 
Error in named configuration:
zone enum4red.com/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone enum4red.com/IN: has no NS records
zone enum4red.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/enum4red.com/IN: bad zone
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
                                                           [FAILED]
umount: /var/named/chroot/var/named: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

logs are:

```
Oct  7 04:35:46 localhost named: zone enum4red.com/IN: has 0 SOA records
Oct  7 04:35:46 localhost named: zone enum4red.com/IN: has no NS records
Oct  7 04:35:46 localhost named: zone enum4red.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Oct  7 04:35:46 localhost named: _default/enum4red.com/IN: bad zone
Oct  7 04:35:46 localhost named: zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
Oct  7 04:35:46 localhost named: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
Oct  7 04:35:46 localhost named: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Oct  7 04:35:46 localhost named: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Oct  7 04:35:46 localhost named: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
```

any idea what went wrong?

Comment: The error messages tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong:

```
Error in named configuration:
zone enum4red.com/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone enum4red.com/IN: has no NS records
zone enum4red.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Go to this directory:

```
/var/named/chroot/var/named
```

Take a look at the zone files for the zone enum4red.com.

Comment: isc bind absolutely despises bad config files.  named-checkconf and named-checkzone are your friends to run /before/ you hit that restart command and find you deprived your network of DNS.  yay.

Comment: got the solution.. ttl entry was missing in zone file records... thank you for your comments :)

Comment: @pratik - Glad you solved it. Please accept this answer so that others know your issue's been resolved.